# Chrome Developer Tools console - log stacking, how do I see re-logged stuff [Screenshot Inside]?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I've just started using the console in Chrome Developer Tools (pretty new to Javascript in general). I noticed that when I consecutively log the same variable twice (an object in this case), that the log stacks this and places a little number icon next to it. I click on this thinking that I'll be able to see the object twice (as it's been updated twice), however nothing happens.

**Image for more clarification:**

[image]

As you can see there's a little "2" in a blue circle next to the `Object` drop-down. The first log would've had `Object.num` at 3, and the second at 4, however all I can see is the second.

Any answers as to how to see both logs would be appreciated.

:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This custom `log` function will log a "snapshot" of the object, so in your example you'll see the updated "num" property of your object reflected in every call to `log`.

It sort of cheats by manually logging each property of the object into a "console group." But, it ends up looking pretty close to the normal `console.log` output (without the weird behavior you point out in your question).

Also, it probably only works in Chrome.

```
function log(obj) {
    console.groupCollapsed(({}).toString.call(obj).split(' ')[1].split(']')[0]);
    for (var k in obj) obj.hasOwnProperty(k) && console.log(k + ': ', obj[k]);
    console.log('__proto__: ', obj.__proto__);
    console.groupEnd();
}​
```

Try it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ULfBV/).

---

Excellent question, by the way. I just learned a lot about the console I didn't know before. :)

Answer (score 6):

This happens because you're logging the same exact object twice. Even if this didn't result in stacking, you'd only see `num' being 4, as the console does not - to the best of my knowledge, at least - grab copies of the objects you log. This is occasionally somewhat inconvenient, I agree.

One way I just thought of of ensuring that you'll get separate logs - but with added memory usage - is to do something like

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

(This should work, at least.) If your object is relatively simple to interpret by eye, you could just omit the `JSON.parse` there and use the JSON string form of your object for logging.

I also suggest looking into the `debugger;` statement - whenever encountered in a JS program, it'll make the environment halt execution of code and break out to the script debugger. It may or may not be more apt for whatever you're debugging.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en#message-stacking), message stacking can be turned off by enabling timestamps in the general console settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me before too. The only solution I could find was to output something in between the two output calls. So for example, if you have this:

```
console.log(var);
...
console.log(var);
```

make it:

```
console.log(var);
console.log('asdf');
...
console.log(var);
```